# RPC port 8332 not accessible after reboot

Tags: bitcoin-core, json-rpc

I have compiled and installed Bitcoin Core for the first time on Debian 11. Everything is up and running except that RPC port 8332 is not accessible after a reboot.

I get the following error running `bitcoin-cli getblockcount`:

error: timeout on transient error: Could not connect to the server 127.0.0.1:8332

If I then run `systemctl restart bitcoind` then everything works fine.

What could be wrong?

---

`systemctl status bitcoind` shows that it is up and running just fine after a reboot.

Look at this after the reboot:

```
$ netstat -nap | grep bitcoin | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8333            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      456/bitcoind        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8334          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      456/bitcoind        
tcp6       0      0 ::1:8332                :::*                    LISTEN      456/bitcoind        
tcp6       0      0 :::8333                 :::*                    LISTEN      456/bitcoind
```

And then after `systemctl restart bitcoind`:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8332          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      532/bitcoind        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8333            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      532/bitcoind        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8334          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      532/bitcoind        
tcp6       0      0 ::1:8332                :::*                    LISTEN      532/bitcoind        
tcp6       0      0 :::8333                 :::*                    LISTEN      532/bitcoind
```

For some reason the 8332 port is not opened on reboot.

Comment: Do you have a logfile configured? if so, does it show anything interesting?

Answer (score 0):

When you restart, run `systemctl status bitcoind` and see if everything is fine. You can also run `$BITCOIN_HOME/

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to finish your answer ...?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding the following to the bincoin.conf:

```
rpcbind=0.0.0.0
rpcport=8332
rpcallowip=192.168.0.1/255.255.255.0
```